# doesn't return a row when using combined string columns in where clause in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a dynamic query that filters the main query
All is working fine except that when i try to use a combined string column it doesn't return any row. Is there anything I need to do make this work? I try to use alias in having clause but it doesn't work too

[image: Without Filter]

[image: With Filter]

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CONCAT()` like:

```
... CONCAT(Employees.emp_last_name, ', ', Employees.emp_first_name) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query result show the name is Parungao, Mark Anthony (without space in the beginning), but your query condition is like '% '

Remove space after % in your query.

```
and Employees.emp_last_name + ', ' + Employees.emp_first_name like '%Parungao, Mark Anthony%'
```

Answer (score 0):

query for firstname and lastname seperatly

```
and Employees.emp_last_name like '%Parungao%'
and Employees.emp_first_name like '%Mark Anthony%'
```

looking closely at your picture, i'd say, you have a few spaces after Parungao.